# Can I make sure that only reference variable can accept the result of a function?

Tags: c++

Let's say I have this function

```cpp
class Entity;

Entity& CreateEntity(){
    Entity* e = new Entity();
    entityVec.emplace_back(e);
    return *e;
}
```

Currently, both of the code below would compile.

```cpp
Entity a = CreateEntity();
Entity& b = CreateEntity();
```

However, I want to make sure that only a reference variable can accept the result of the function. As otherwise, the code will have a lot of unintended behaviors.

In otherwords, is there any way to make `Entity a = CreateEntity()` throws a error, and only `Entity& b = CreateEntity()` is allowed?

If not, is there any way or pattern that can enforce it?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain how your function transformed a pointer into a reference, somehow? `e` is an `Entity *`, so how did it manage to become an `Entity &`?

Comment: They probably forgot a `*` in the function body.

Comment: I forgot to dereference it. Thanks for the reminder

Comment: Is it possible you want to disable copy construction/assignment? It sounds like that may be what you're thinking about.

Comment: Well, you can always delete the copy constructor, however that would prevent these objects from being placed into a vector. I suspect that this is an XY problem, and you're asking how to keep these objects from getting copied. If so, I have bad news: they are already getting copied all the time, by the virtue of being placed into a vector. In any case, there's no way to do strictly what you're asking. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik In OP's code, it is a *pointer* that is put into the vector, so a deleted copy c'tor wouldn't bother that particular case.

Comment: Yes, make it non-copyable. That's why iostreams are always passed around as references or pointers.

Comment: Maybe you want to return a pointer rather than a reference?

Comment: C++11 and later, simply `delete` the copy constructor and assignment operator.   Before C++11, declare copy constructor and assignment operators as `private`, and don't define them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wish there was a compiler warning for this. Because what you are addressing is a real concern for performance particularly when using the STL.

Microsoft Code Analysis could be what you are looking for:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/new-safety-rules-in-c-core-check/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c26820?view=vs-2019

If you are in control of the class you are worried about copying here is a possible solution. A workaround is to simply delete the copy constructors/operator=.
I wrote up a macro that does just this:

```cpp
// Disallow the use of the copy constructor and copy assignment operator for a class:
// Note: prefer to place this in public for better compiler error messages (Scott Meyers Effective C++)
#define UTIL_DELETE_COPY_AND_ASSIGN(udt)       \
    udt(const udt&)             = delete; \
    udt& operator =(const udt&) = delete;
```

```
class foobar
{
public:
    UTIL_DELETE_COPY_AND_ASSIGN(foobar);
}
```

If you still wanna keep copy constructor/assign functionality, you can simply make a more explicit version of these functions so users know what they are getting.

```
class foobar
{
public:
    foobar DeepCopy(); {...}
    UTIL_DELETE_COPY_AND_ASSIGN(foobar);
}
```